# How does the ODE function in R do the calculation

Tags: r, ode

I am using the ODE function In R in order to solve this equation:

```
library(deSolve)
FluidH <- function(t,state,parameters) {
with(as.list(c(state,parameters)),
dh <- Qin/A - ((5073.3*h^2+6430.1*h)/(60*A)) 
 list(c(dh))
  })
}

parameters <- c(Qin =10, A=6200)
state<- c(h=0.35)
time <- seq(0,2000,by=1)
out <- ode(y= state, func = FluidH, parms = parameters, times = time)
```

I might be missing something with math, but when I try to calculate h by myself by assigning the initial state I don't get the same numbers as the output of the function!
for example to calculate h at time 1 : h=h0+ dh*dt -> h= 0.35 + 10/6200 - ((5073.3*h^2+6430.1*h)/(60*6200))=0.3438924348
and the output of ode gives 0.343973044412394

Can anyone tell what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You computed the Euler step with step size `dt=1`. The solver uses a higher order method with (usually) a smaller step size that is adapted to meet the default error tolerances of `1e-6` for relative and absolute error. The step-size `1` that you give only determines where the numerical solution is sampled for the output, internally the solver may use many more or sometimes even less steps (interpolating the output values).

Comment: I understand! Thank you